# Как с помощью регулярного выражения, отловить последнее слово в кавычках в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустим, имеется файл, содержащий множество строк по типу:

word1 "word2" "word3" "word4".

Необходимо с помощью регулярного выражения получить последнее слово, в последних кавычках, в данном примере - word4. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: `"([^"]+)"[^"]*$`

Comment: а там * перед $ добавить не надо?

Comment: Ну если полностью, то `^.*"([^"]+)"[^"]*$`. Или `^.*("[^"]+")[^"]*$`, если кавычки надо сохранить.